# how to place 2 coredata attributes in a single tableview cell. (swift4)

Tags: core-data, attributes, tableview, swift4, cell

My code right now calls one core data attribute "lorde" and places it on a tableview cell. I want the cell to display both "lorde" and other attribute "num". I want both attributes to be printed on
**cell.textLabel?.text**.

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let title = itemsName[indexPath.row]

    let cell = tazbleView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for : indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = title.value(forKey: "lorde") as? String


    return cell

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer this way
It looks more nice and not stop of using when just one attribute exists

```
let attr1 = title.value(forKey: "lorde") as? String
let attr2 = title.value(forKey: "num") as? String 
cell.textLabel?.text = [attr2, attr1].flatMap { $0 }.reduce("", +)
```

Comment: How could it print out like "Team :"attr2 "House :" attr1

Comment: yes, you can do something like this 
["Team:",attr2, "House:", attr1].flatMap { $0 }.reduce("", +)

Comment: Do you think you could also answer this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51193137/how-to-sort-2-attributes-called-from-coredata-in-a-tableview-cell-swfit4

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the two strings with the `+` operator.

```
guard let lorde = title.value(forKey: "lorde"),
      let num = title.value(forKey: "num")
else { fatalError("cannot unwrap title keys") }

cell.textLabel?.text = lorde + num
```

Comment: looks good expect for lorde + num. I am getting the compile error :Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two 'Any' operands.

Comment: Try to cast them as `String`: `let lorde = title.value(forKey: "lorde") as String`. Disclaimer: typed in browser.

Comment: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'

Comment: try `as? String` instead of `as String`

Comment: that works but then getting a runtime error with the else part that states : Thread 1: Fatal error: cannot unwrap title keys

Comment: That could happen because lorde and or num is nil.

Comment: As soon as the code complies the thing crashes. I dont even have the chance to enter into coredata.

Comment: Are they both strings in your data model?